# Unable to create directory using make_path

Tags: perl

I was trying to create a directory and a sub-directory within it using Perl.
Here is the code:

```
  #!/usr/bin/perl
  use strict;
  use warnings;
  use Cwd qw(abs_path);
  use File::Path qw(make_path remove_tree);
  my $path = abs_path();
  my @create = make_path($path , '/test/data' , {
                                                  verbose => 1,
                                                  mode => 0777,
                                                })
               or die "failed to create directory /test/data $!";
```

It shows the following error:-

```
    failed to create directory /test/data  at ./perl_project.pl line 7
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Tip: `my $path = abs_path();`  can be simplified to with `my $path = ".";`

Comment: Tip: `my $path = "."; make_path($path . '/test/data', ...);` can be simplified to `make_path('test/data', ...);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create the path `/test/data` at your current directory, change:

```
 my @create = make_path($path , '/test/data' , {
```

to:

```
 my @create = make_path($path . '/test/data' , {
 #                            ^
```

Since you used a comma in [make_path](https://perldoc.perl.org/File::Path), your code attempts to create 2 directories: one at the current directory (`$path`) and another at the absolute path `/test/data`.